# Regex: How to capture all matched values of a regex capture group with repetition?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture a list of delimitered values such as:

```
abc, def, ghi
```

Ideally, I get a list of "abc", "def", "ghi" while validating that the input at the same time.

I've been attempting to use a regex expression like this:

```
^([^,]*)(?:, *([^,]+))*$
```

when I read the [claim](http://bugs.python.org/issue7132) that:

> For now, when capturing groups are used within repetitions, it is
>   impossible to capure what they match individually within the list of
>   matched repetitions.

1. Is this true?
2. If so, how to properly capture the values? Must I manually separate them into pieces, then run a regex on them to validate each individual value?

Comment: Yes it is true, but a solution depends on what language you are coding in. Please let us know. In Perl you could do it by writing `my @tokens = "abc, def, ghi" =~ /[^,]+/g;`

Comment: @Borodin is correct, there are ways to do that, but they differ depending on the language.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `split` :

**Perl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my @list = split/,\s*/, $str;
dump@list;
```

**output:**

```
("abc", "def", "ghi")
```

If you want to use regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my $str = "abc, def, ghi";
my @list = $str =~ /[^, ]+/g;
dump@list;
```

gives the same output.

**PHP**

```
$str = "abc, def, ghi";
$list = preg_split('/[, ]+/', $str);
print_r($list);
```

or

```
preg_match_all('/[^, ]+/', $str, $list);
print_r($list);
```